# Asp.net: Custom Role and Membership Provider, LoginStatus Control not reacting

Tags: asp.net, membership-provider, web-controls

Involved in a project where one half of the team are building the db and web services layer and we are builing a separate, front end, web service consuming site.

We are building a custom role and membership provider which will operate via the web services layer.

Just doing some early prototyping, setting roles, checking page permissions and seeing if menu items switch off and on depending on the role etc.

One strange item has come up. The inbuilt loginview control correctly switches between the LoggedInTemplate and AnonymousTemplate depending on whether someone is logged in or not.

However the LoginStatus control does not react at all. It always displays the LoggedOut text.

I would have guessed the LoginView and LoginStatus would operate the same i.e. just plumb in the new provider and they would work off of it.

Authentication is Forms also of course.

Anyone aware of any particular settings to watch for when using the LoginStatus control with custom providers?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once all the role and provider methods were used correctly - all was well with that one